# How to prove this trivial idea - boundary tangent interior exterior

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have a closed bounded shape S in euclidean space. And this shape has a smooth boundary at some point A, and there's a tangent line L to the boundary of S at A.

I want to prove that if I take any curve going through A, that is smooth at A, such that the tangent to the curve at A is not parallel to L, then the curve intersects both the interior and exterior of S.

Comment: I guess $L$ has to be a hyperplane tangled at $A$, because otherwise there are trivial counterexamples. For instance, if $S$ is a closed ball in $\Bbb R^3$ centered at the origin $O$ then each circle $C$ going through $A$ and centered at $O$ has a tangent $L_C$ at $A$ which belongs to the plane containing $C$. Any of $C$’s don’t intersect the interior of $S$, but $L_C$’s, corresponding to distinct $C$’s, are not parallel.